# Why doesn't my code work in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

this is my code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool a = false;
    char b='p';
    int c=0;

    while (a != true) {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            b = _getch();
        }
        if (b=='w') {
            c++;
            cout << c << " ";
       }
        else if (b == 'c') {
            cout << "hello";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is where when I press 'w' I want it to print out the value of c and it should be repeating until i press another input for `_kbhit()` right? because now it add 1 to c then prints c and when i press w again samething. What's wrong with my visual studio I'm using community 2017 I've tried to uninstall it and install it again but same problem occurs.

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly compile.

Comment: Once you get the program to build properly and without error or warnings, then I suggest that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially learn how to use the Visual Studio debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: well i can compile it but i know im missing the <> on the conio.h and iostream but when i put them around the conio.h and iostream they just dissapeared

Comment: @SavannPojken _"but when i put them around the conio.h and iostream they just dissapeared "_ Only if you miss to indent your code correctly by four blanks. Also note that `conio.h` isn't a standard c++ header.

Comment: I think the poster has done a perfectly reasonable job of asking a question, to which it turns out the answer is *not* immediately obvious at all. It does *not* deserve the down-votes it's gotten.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into seems to be a result of a recently added bug in `_getch()`/`_kbhit`.

For an extended key (e.g., a cursor key) it's documented that `_getch()` returns either a 0x0 or 0xe0 followed by the scan code for the key that was actually pressed. What's **not** documented is that if the user presses a non-extended key, `_kbhit` will still return `true` twice in succession, and calls to `_getch()` will return the key code the first time, and 0x0 the second time.

In your code, when the user presses 'w' or 'c', `_kbhit` will return `true` not just once (as you'd expect) but *twice*. The first time you call it, it'll return the scan code of the key, and the second it'll return a 0 byte.

What's happening in your code is that you're reading the scan code, printing something appropriately, then `_kbhit` is returning `true` again, so you read the '\0' byte, set `b` to '\0', and then (since you don't have any code to do anything when `b` is 0) you (repeatedly) do nothing until the next time the user presses a key.

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2017

Comment: well the same problem ocurs when i set b to NULL or \0 so i think it's something is missing in my visual studio because it works on my school computer but not on my home pc

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the program behaves the way you want it to. If I press 'w', it goes into an infinite loop of increasing the value of `c` and printing it. Pressing any other key stops printing and pressing 'c' goes on the same infinite loop and prints `hello`. Doesn't seem to be any problems as far as the posted code is concerned. Also, I would like to say the same as @Someprogrammerdude, if it compiles, but doesn't behave the way you want it to, it's an issue with the code, not the IDE and/or compiler.

Hypothetical answer: Your computer might always be thinking that a key is pressed, thus `kbhit()` always returns true. This maybe caused by a bad mouse/keyboard/controller driver and/or configuration. The code is fine, your PC is not.

Comment: Inside the 'if(_kbhit) ` block try couting something. This way you can determine if my hypothesis is correct. If it is, try using keyboard hooks and see which ones are active for whatever reason. That' s my best guess anyway.